# Java hashmap access from different class

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a HashMap with setter and getter in a class, when i try to access it from different class, i am getting null

how do i access HashMap from different class ?
here is the code

```
public class test {

    private HashMap<String, String> test= new HashMap<String, String>();

    public void settest(String key, String value) {
        test.put(key, value);
    }

    public String gettest(String key) {
        return test.get(key);       
    }

}

public class b{
    test ts=new test();
    ts.settest("location","Chicago");
}


public class c{
    test ts=new test();
    System.out.println(ts.gettest("location"));
}
```

in the class c i am getting out put as null

Comment: Please, take a look at this [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: (Leaving aside that your code is uncompilable) You create _two_ instances of `test`, each with its own map. You place a key in one map, and try and retrieve it from the other.

Comment: The variable `ts` in class `b` isn't related to the variable `ts` in class `c`. These are different instances of `test`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have created two different instances of `test` class, so their HashMaps would be different too.

I don't know your final goal, but one solution is to define your HashMap as a static field. In this case, these two instances of `test` class will use a common HashMap.

Your modified code:

```
public class test {

    private static HashMap<String, String> test= new HashMap<String, String>();

    public void settest(String key, String value) {
        test.put(key, value);
    }

    public String gettest(String key) {
        return test.get(key);       
    }

}

public class b{
    test ts=new test();
    ts.settest("location","Chicago");
}


public class c{
    test ts=new test();
    System.out.println(ts.gettest("location"));
}
```